# Como mandar um dado para uma activity já criada?

Tags: android, android-activity

Estou na *activity A* e mandei um dado pelo `putExtras()` para a *activity B* que ainda não foi criada, neste caso funcionou, mas agora tenho q mandar um dado da *activity B* para a *activity A* que já foi criada e não posso dar `finish()` nela.

Alguém sabe como fazer?

Estou passando e recebendo dados pelo `bundle()`, mas se tiver outra forma também aplico.

Comment: A Activity B não vai sair da tela?

Comment: sim a B é um formulário depois que preencho ele eu salvo, dou um finish() e mando um dado (apenas para confirmar que foi salvo) de volta para activity A, está deve ficar sempre aberta.

Comment: Você pode criar um método na ActivityA e chamar o método criado pela ActivityB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar o método `startActivityForResult()` que permite que uma **ActivityA** chame uma **ActivityB** e receba um retorno da mesma.

Para fazer isso, em sua **ActivityA** chame a **ActivityB** usando o método `startActivityForResult()`. Um exemplo:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
/* 
   Crie seu Bundle e coloque dados
*/
startActivityForResult(i, 1); // O '1' é um id para a operação
```

Na sua **ActivityB** faça o procedimento normal de pegar os dados da **ActivityA**e quando você for retorná-los escreva o seguinte código na **ActivityB**:

```
Intent intentRetorno = new Intent();
intentRetorno.putExtra("resultado", dadoDeRetorno);
setResult(RESULT_OK, intentRetorno);
finish();
```

Depois, faça a sua **ActivityA** implementar o método `onActivityResult()`.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            String result = data.getStringExtra("resultado");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: valew cara, exatamente o que eu preciso. Funcionou certinho aqui! Obrigadão!